# why does this cucumber code fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I have this code : https://github.com/roelof1967/tamara
But when I do cucumber it fails with this error message : https://gist.github.com/4008123

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong with my code?

Roelof

Edit 1:
Code that fails:

```
class Output  
def messages    
   @messages ||= []  
end    
def puts(message)    
    messages << message  
end    
def output    
   @output ||= Output.new  
end
end

When /^he logs in$/ do   
   visit("/users/sign_in")  
   fill_in('Email', :with => @user.email)  
   fill_in('Password', :with => @user.password)  
   click_button('Sign in')
end

Then /^he should see "(.*?)"$/ do |message|  
  @output.messages.should include (message)
end
```

And here is the error message :

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass NoMethodError)      
./features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:6:in `/^he logs in$/'          
features/login.feature:5:in `When he logs in'
```

Comment: Post the code and error message. Don't make us go to random links to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Do this for your solution:

**Step 1** : create home controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

**step 2** : create **`home`** folder in `view` and create **`index.html.erb`** file and your content look like as a example

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
  <h1> <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %> </h1>
<% else %>
  <h1> <%= link_to "Sign Up", "/users/sign_up" %> |<%= link_to "Sign In", user_session_path %> </h1>
<% end %>
```

**step 3** : now your **`login.feature`** file look like

```
Feature: login and authecation

Scenario: log in as existing user
  Given a user "roelof" exists
  When he logs in
  Then he should see "Signed in successfully."
  And he should see "Sign Out"

Scenario: log in with bad password
  Given a user "Aslak" exists
  When he logs in with a bad password
  Then he should not see "Welcome, Aslak"
  And he should see "Login failed"
```

**step 4** now, run `cucumber`

your scenario "log in as existing user" will pass.